# convert matlab code to python: SMOP not generating output file

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, converters

I am trying to convert matlab files to python using [SMOP](https://github.com/victorlei/smop) (Small Matlab/Octave to Python compiler) without installing SMOP itself but making sure all dependencies like ply and networkx are installed.

I issue the following instruction, as given in the SMOP github page to convert the matlab r8_random.m file provided in the smop directory:

```
$ # browse to directory of smop
$ python3.5 main.py r8_random.m -o r8_random.py
```

My terminal shows me the following output:

```
WARNING: Token 'CLASSDEF' defined, but not used
WARNING: Token 'END_UNEXPECTED' defined, but not used
WARNING: There are 2 unused tokens
Generating LALR tables
WARNING: 1 shift/reduce conflict
```

But I don't get any file converted from the matlab file. I'm not sure how to interpret the terminal output messages and what else to check. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I could make it to work but I had to Install the smop package:

```
sudo pip3.5 install smop
```

and then on the bash I issued the command (after `cd`-ing to the matlab-file directory):

```
smop r8_random.py
```

which gave me an output file `r8_random.py`

But it will still be worthwile to know if it could actually be used without installing as mentioned on the github page